# What is causing 'FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page'

Tags: pagespeed-insights

We are getting desktop only error for https://www.southwarkeba.org.uk as follows:

> ### An error has occurred
>
> Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)

Not getting this issue with other speed checking tools that I use such as PingDom or GTMetrix

Comment: I notice this occurs especially when pointing the tool at Google.com

Comment: Looks like this error is occurring with multiple sites for various reasons, the error message is not clear enough. Maybe LH should provide a more descriptive error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

I got a very similar error while assigning a `userId` guid in a cookie to a variable that was never getting retrieved by PageSpeed Insights.

The process is that a user accesses our site, if they are authenticated, it grabs their authenticated `userId`, otherwise it creates an anonymous guid and assigns it to `userId` and then to a cookie. It then grabbed the `userId` from the cookie.

PageSpeed Insights is of course the latter (anonymous) and is simply not retrieving the `userId` from the cookie (and probably not creating the cookie in the first place).

The only difference in error is our `Details: net:` is: `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Since your error is `ERR_TIMED_OUT` (and assuming it's not a genuine network failure), I would look at parts of your code that are not accessible by PageSpeed Insights (e.g. a subsequent resource that's actually down, a resource authenticated by user credentials, or authenticated by ip address, etc).

I realize I'm late to the party here, and the OP has probably found a solution already, but maybe this will help someone else down the road as googling my specific error returns zero results.